# RequestReduce - How to use it?

Tags: asp.net, requestreduce

I can't seem to understand how RequestReduce works. I've installed all the components via NuGet, except the SQL feature which I don't need. Now what else should I do, I run my site via IIS Express and it doesn't generate any js and css files, not errors nothing. How exactly I suppose to use it?

I'm developing my website in ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having trouble getting RequestReduce to work on IIS Express. Exact same config/site  works as expected in IIS 7.5.